# How to handle fancybox iframe close event in the parent?

Tags: .net, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

Here is my code for fancybox iframe

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            $("#popup").fancybox({
                fitToView: false,
                autoSize: false,
                autoDimensions: false,
                title: "Item Details",
                width: 965,
                height: 525,
                padding: 0,
                helpers: {
                    title: {
                        type: 'float'
                    },
                    overlay: {
                        css: {
                            'background': 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                onClosed: function () {
                   alert('Hi');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to handle iframe close event, but the above code is not working.
Please let me know where am I going wrong Please.
Thanks.

Comment: your code is perfectly working check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Yy4jr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using fancybox v2.x because the API options in your code ... if so `onClosed` is not a valid option for this version but for v1.3.x.

You have to use `afterClose` instead :

```
afterClose : function () {
 alert('yep, you just closed fancybox v2.x');
}
```

BTW, neither `transitionIn` or `transitionOut` are valid v2.x API options, check the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the valid options for v2.x